# Why is my second printf not called when expected?

Tags: c, input, scanf, getchar

I'm just learning to program in C and am a bit confused about something going on with `scanf` and `getchar`. I understand that using something like `scanf("%d", &i)` will read an integer input, but leave the following newline character in the input buffer (which is why one must clear the input buffer by looking for `getchar() == '\n'` before using `getchar` after a `scanf` call.

Here is my simple (incorrect) program that reads an integer, and then a character input, and prints them back to the user:

```
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%d\n", &i);

    printf("Enter a char: ");
    char ch = getchar();

    printf("You entered integer: %d\nYou entered character: %c\n", i, ch);

    return 0;
}
```

If I leave the newline character off in my `scanf` format String (so just have `"%d"`), it makes sense that as soon as the user types in an integer and hits enter that integer will be read and stored in `i`, and the program will continue to execute ("Enter a char: " immediately printed, and `ch` storing the newline character).

However, with the format String of `"%d\n"` I encounter unexpected behavior. When a user enters an integer and hits enter, I expected "Enter a char: " to be printed. Instead, you can keep hitting enter and nothing happens until you decide to enter a different character. So you can type "10", hit enter 6 times, then type in "d" and `getchar()` reads that "correctly". The whole program output would look like this

```
Enter an integer: 10




d
Enter a char: You entered integer: 10
You entered character: d
```

Why is it that my program stalls until a character is entered? It seems odd that my second `printf` function is called seemingly AFTER the call to `getchar` (since the character read is entered before "Enter a char: " gets printed).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am just trying to further my understanding of this nuance in C.

Comment: Don't use `scanf()`. If you don't exactly know how it works, then that's why. If you do know how it works, then that's why. [We can have nicer things](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/fgets.html).

Comment: @H2CO3 Understood. It was simply an exercise. I am trying to gain further understanding to exactly how `scanf()` treats whitespace. In this case, newline characters.

Comment: Yes, that's nice, I definitely do **not** want to discourage you from learning. Just as one should understand raw pointers in C++ (albeit it's typically not used), you should surely have an understanding of `scanf()`. I only warned that it's generally not the best option to use in production.

Comment: @H2CO3 Fair enough, that is also what I've read (and I believe it is mentioned in the book I am reading). But surely it has its uses (as does `goto` in some very rare circumstances). What are safer alternatives? I'm jumping ahead of my current understanding, but I _think_ `scanf` can do some fancy input formatting when mixed with regular expressions. Is there a safer alternative for that also?

Comment: The concept I like the best is: one function - one purpose. Functions that try to do more than one thing are inherently flawed. `scanf()` tries to do I/O and parsing at the same time. Not so good. If you can, prefer separating the I/O part (`fgets()`, `getchar()`, `getline()`, `fread()`, `read()`, etc.) from the parsing part. For parsing, there also are useful standard library functions such as `strtok_r()`, `str[r]chr()`, `strstr()`, maybe eventually `sscanf()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a `scanf` format string, any sequence of white-space characters will match any amount of white space in the input. So your `\n` will match any number of new-lines, and `scanf` will only return once it encounters a non-space character.

Comment: Well that clears that up. Can't believe I missed that :-/ Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but you can try something like this:

```
printf("Enter an integer: ");
scanf("%d\n", &i);
fflush(stdin);
```

Answer (score 1):

The scanf [docs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fscanf.3.html) (for linux) says:

"A sequence of white-space characters (space, tab, newline, etc.; see isspace(3)).  This directive matches any amount of white space, including none, in the input."

Basically \n doesn't match a verbatim newline, it matches any amount of whitespace until a non-whitespace character is encountered.

So your `scanf("%d\n", &i)` eats all the whitespace and doesn't return until it sees a non-whitespace character. You would get the same effect with  `scanf("%d\t", &i)` or `scanf("%d ", &i)`

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. The reference I was reading mentioned this but it didn't click on first or second glance. The wording in that reference is much more straightforward.